# Which is the better way of storing date and time in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

i would like to store the date and time in the following format in the database

a) DD-MM-YYYY or  i could add up HH-MM
b) as my servers are located in US i would like to fetch the time as per IST. now that will be GMT : +5:30

earlier i used to store the date in mysql in this format timestamp(int(11)):1291746600. i used to convert the date with strtotime();
currently my intention of storing the date is just to store and display. in the future i would like to calculate the no. of days, months etc.

which would be the best possible solution for this?

P:S : i would appreciate if someone could explain me which datatype to use and how to use it with PHP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`DATETIME` fields](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)! They are the best format to store dates in mySQL. They offer proper indexing and optimization, and you can use the full range of mySQL's [date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Any specific format you need to output the fields in, you can create from a DATETIME field using [`DATE_FORMAT()`.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

MySQL doesn't support time zones in DATETIME fields - you will usually set a [global time zone](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) on the server and use that.

There's good related reading on Timezones in these questions:

- [MySQL: keep server timezone or user timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852223/mysql-keep-server-timezone-or-user-timezone)
- [Lost in dates and timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978473/lost-in-dates-and-timezones)

Answer (score 3):

Use a datetime field.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

You will have access to a lot of function for date  manipulation.

If you want still to use a varchar use the ISO-TIME format (YYYY-MM-DD) not the us.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use `DATETIME` data type.
For more operations on date and time have a look at functions listed here
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html